Challenging yet accessible problems for middle school students
I'm currently working for a Math summer camp and am tasked with providing 7th grade students with math problems that are challenging yet accessible problems that could be solved by most students within, say, a week if they put their minds to it. They are very bright and can pick up on patterns relatively quickly (and can write simple proofs), but they have not formally taken algebra yet (they might be familiar with some rudimentary concepts but thats about it). I've looked around and most problems I've found for this grade level just by googling are either too mundane (of the "solve for $x$" variety of questions) or require a bit more mathematical background (particularly with number theory/algebra) than they currently have. Two questions which I feel strike a nice balance between being challenging yet accessible are the ones below:

A palindrome number is a number that can be read the same when its digits are reversed. For example, the number 12321 is a 5-digit palindrome number and 767767 is a 6-digit palindrome number. Find a number larger than 1 that divides every 4-digit palindrome number. You must clearly explain or prove how you know.


What is the digit sum of the product of the 94-digit number consisting of all “9”s and the 94-digit number consisting of all “4”s?

I'm currently looking for a few more! If anyone has any suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Can they use induction?

I think an induction question could potentially work!

mathcounts is a good source for that age group.

You could try
: Find all natural $n$ such that $n^2+1$ is divisible by $n+1$

Simple permutations or basic principle of counting problems, like find the number of 3 digit numbers that don't have any repeating digits...may be suitable

I don't know exactly what level is 7th-grade (I haven't the same system in my country). Could you indicate the mean age of these students ?

@JeanMarie They are around 12-13 years old!

Consider using "cryptarithmetic problems", of the type SEND + MORE = MONEY.

Magic squares or magic stars are a good source as well.

You could get plenty of inspiration from searching for questions on algebra/precalculus/geometry/number theory/etc. from past olympiads and competitions, although those questions are typically designed to be answered well within one week...
